# View Pager not work properly in Real Device Tablet Android 10 inch

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I have working with android project that use `Fragment` and `ViewPager` that use many layout to add in view pager.

I have build my working project with android sdk **api min version 14** and target sdk to **api 17** in android.

When I test my application in my virtual device it working properly and such as the view pager with more than 15 pages.

But When I test in my real devices I use **Fujitsu M532** It has lag. And view pager must not responding to switch to next page. What properly do my application goes wrong? Any suggestion to this problems ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are there error in the LogCat? What kind of Layouts are you using?, You might be overloading the Device and that's why it gets lagg, although I don't think that's the problem....

Comment: I don't know if there's any logcat error I haven't see it in logcat. The layout I use almost using `RelativeLayout` in all layout. When I combine it all in view pager it has lag. and there is no ANR Also.. What do you mean **overloading** with my device?